# Pandas: how to merge df with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
number   A    B    C
123      10   10   1
123      10   11   1
123      18   27   1
456      10   18   2
456      42   34   2
789      13   71   3
789      19   108  3
789      234  560  4
```

and second df

```
number    A    B
123       18   27
456       32   19
789       234  560
```

I need, if `number, A, B`is equal to this column in second df, add that to new df and also add string with `C` is equal string, that we add earlier. 
Desire output

```
number   A   B   C
  123    10  10  1
  123    10  11  1
  123    18  27  1
  789    234 560 4
```

How can I write this condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to give df2 a dummy column:

```
In [11]: df2["in_df2"] = True
```

then you can do the merge:

```
In [12]: df1.merge(df2, how="left")
Out[12]:
   number    A    B  C in_df2
0     123   10   10  1    NaN
1     123   10   11  1    NaN
2     123   18   27  1   True
3     456   10   18  2    NaN
4     456   42   34  2    NaN
5     789   13   71  3    NaN
6     789   19  108  3    NaN
7     789  234  560  4   True
```

Now, we only want those groups which contains a True:

```
In [13]: df1.merge(df2, how="left").groupby(["number", "C"]).filter(lambda x: x["in_df2"].any())
Out[13]:
   number    A    B  C in_df2
0     123   10   10  1    NaN
1     123   10   11  1    NaN
2     123   18   27  1   True
7     789  234  560  4   True
```

Comment: That question confused me in many ways... but i'm about 50% sure you got it right.

Comment: LOL, I'm also quite confused, until now. I still couldn't think of the rationale behind question. But anyway, nice answer! Upvoted!

Comment: I think you've deciphered what the OP is asking... just be interesting to see what's supposed to happen where the `number` group has more than one eligible `C` candidate...

Comment: Another method would be to do `df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)` to add the `_merge` column and test where `_merge=='both'` and `filter` the same way you've done but this looks right to me, the OP seems to want to do a `isin` with `number` col where the merged rows have any matches

Comment: Can you say, it compare all column in the string? It returns `Empty dataframe` to my df. How can I compare only some column?